# Append a line a file with a missing word

Tags: text-processing

I have a file named `xyz.txt` and it contains three lines such as

```
I am ok.
I am fine.
all good.
```

I need to find a line with does't contain `am` and append the line to the previous line

For the given example the output I need is

```
I am ok.
I am fine. all good.
```

And also the script needs to be applicable for a large size file. For example, if there are 10 lines in a file and 'am' is missing in lines 3 and 7, then line 3 should be appended to the 2nd line and the 7th line append to the 6th line.

Comment: If there are two lines without `am`, both get appended to the previous line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**awk** solution (here assuming GNU or busybox `awk` for the `\<`, `\>` word boundary operators):

Extended sample `file`:

```
I am ok.
I am fine.
all good.
am I sleeping?
how's that
I am sure
about that
and think on.
For that I am now
```

---

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",(NR==1? "": (!/\<am\>/? OFS:ORS)),$0 }END{ print "" }' file
```

- `"%s%s"` - format string with 2 specifications. The 1st `%s` of them if for potential item "leading" delimiter:

  - for the 1st record (`NR==1`) it will be `""`(empty string)
  - for record that doesn't contain `am` word - `OFS`(output field separator, i.e. space)
  - for records containing `am` word - `ORS`(output record separator, i.e. the newline by default)

---

The output:

```
I am ok.
I am fine. all good.
am I sleeping? how's that
I am sure about that and think on.
For that I am now
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Its working fine in my project..:)

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;/\n.*am/!s/\n/ /;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

Explanation:

- Append the `N` next line (or print the last line and end)
- If the second line doesn't include `am` (the trailing `!` negates the address pattern `\n.*am`), replace the newline with a space
- If this replacement was made, loop to the beginning to append another line if necessary (`ta` is a conditional jump to mark `:a`)
- If the second line contains `am` (no replacement was made), `P;D` prints the first line and starts over with the second line

I see, you seem to use linux. With GNU `sed` you can simply write

```
sed ':a;N;/\n.*am/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D'
```